# Error fetching Image file data from Firebase

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, dart, error-handling

I want to display an File image which a user selects from their gallery and can post it as a product Image. However ive been having all kinds of issues trying to display the image and nothing has worked!

My latest update of code was changing the way I fetch the Image from firebase by doing this `image: File(carData['image']),` which in a way removed one of the errors I was getting due to the image not getting displayed but I got another error know which im having issues with solving and it gives me the following error in my stacktrace (After i refresh my app and try to fetch the data i submitted through a form):

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building CarItem(dirty, dependencies: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#6c638], _InheritedTheme, MediaQuery]):
The method '+' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: +("58")
```

Now whats really strange about this is the fact it didnt call my file at all. it skipped that step and due to it not finding an image it took the Value of the "Price" `textFormField` I have built in the app.

Here is my fetch data using firebase:

```
Future<void> fetchAndSetCars() async {
    const url = 'https://mylink.firebaseio.com/cars.json';
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      final extractedData = json.decode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final List<AddCar> loadedCars = [];
      extractedData.forEach((carId, carData) {
        loadedCars.add(AddCar(
          id: carId,
          name: carData['name'],
          city: carData['city'],
          country: carData['country'],
          currencyT: carData['currency'],
          price: carData['price'],
          // date: carData['date'],
          sponsNum: carData['sponsNum'],
          category: carData['category'],
          company: carData['company'],
          model: carData['model'],
          year: carData['year'],
          engine: carData['engine'],
          distanceCovered: carData['distanceCovered'],
          transmission: carData['transmission'],
          oilT: carData['oil type'],
          outColor: carData['outter color'],
          inColor: carData['inner color'],
          description: carData['description'],
          address: carData['address'],
          image: File(carData['image']),
        ));
      });
      _cars = loadedCars;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw (error);
    }
  }
```

Here is how im calling the data in a list that displays all the products:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts_arabic/fonts.dart';

import '../providers/car_provider.dart';
import '../widget/car_item.dart';

class CarsList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarsListState createState() => _CarsListState();
}

class _CarsListState extends State<CarsList> {
    @override
  void initState() {
 Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
  Provider.of<Cars>(context).fetchAndSetCars();
 });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final carsData = Provider.of<Cars>(context);
    final car = carsData.cars;
    return car.isEmpty
        ? Center(
            child: Text(
            'error no car found',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: ArabicFonts.Tajawal,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              package: 'google_fonts_arabic',
            ),
          ))
        : ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 47.0),
            itemCount: car.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, i) => CarItem(
              car[i].id,
              car[i].image,
              car[i].name,
              car[i].model,
              car[i].currencyT,
              car[i].price,
              car[i].distanceCovered,
              car[i].transmission,
              car[i].oilT,
              car[i].year,
              car[i].date,
            ),
          );
  }
}
```

here is how I coded the image diplay in my CarItem:

```
 final String id;
  final File image;
  final String name;
  final String model;
  final String currencyT;
  final String price;
  final double distanceCovered;
  final String transmission;
  final String oilT;
  final String year;
  final DateTime date;

  CarItem(
    this.id,
    this.image,
    this.name,
    this.model,
    this.currencyT,
    this.price,
    this.distanceCovered,
    this.transmission,
    this.oilT,
    this.year,
    this.date,
  );

 Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.35,
                child: GestureDetector(
                  child: Image.file(
                    image,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(
                      MyCarDetails.routeName,
                      arguments: id,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Do you have `URL` in `carData['image']` ?

Comment: Not exactly a URL more like a path this is what gets passed into the firebase `'image` data `"File: '/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.exa..."`

Comment: And you are sure this file in on the device at that place? First i dont know if Image.file() can handle the File:/ prefix, then i am quite sure you need android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE right. I dont think its a useful way to do it this way. Why not store it in Cloud Storage and save that download-URL in firebase? Took me 20 minutes to implement that. But the stack is not (yet) related to loading the image as it seems.

Comment: and i dont understand CarItem code block. Is this part of a build method of a stateless widget or what? Its funny how people paste in code with no relevance like all those attributes and stuff but leaving out the important part.

Comment: the CarItem is how the data is displayed in the app basically itll take the image and place it in the CarItem as  preview Image of the product

Comment: and onTap depending on the product id itll load the products data which explains the onTap arguments: id

Comment: as long as you dont post the complete code to CarItem, its hard to comment further.